# jquery multiple select list update failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

In my php project I have a multiple select dropdown and I'm using `jquery.multiple.select.js`.

My view part is

```
<div class="form-outer box">
  <div class="span12 ">
    <label>Partner</label>
    <select class="span9 check_select " name="partner[]" id="partner" multiple="multiple" >
      <!--<option value="-1">Select</option>-->
      <?php foreach ($member as $memberpart) : ?>
         <option  value="<?php echo $memberpart->members_id; ?>">
           <?php echo $memberpart->members_first_name; ?>
         </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>                                
    </select>
    <a href="#paradd" class="btn" role="button" onclick="clear_message()" data-toggle="modal">
      <i class="icon-plus pull-right" style="margin-top:5px;"></i> 
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I have a PLUS button (`<a>` tag) which opens a modal to add new partner. Now I want to update the multiple select dropdown when a new partner is added using the modal and I call a function when modal is closed as follows,

```
function bulid_select_box(select_box,path,doselect){ 
    var base_url  = $("meta[name=baseurl]").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + path,
        success: function(data) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(select_box).find('option').remove();
            $(select_box).append('<option value="-1">Select</option>');   
            var setselect = '';
            if(doselect){
                setselect = 'selected';
            }
            for(var i=0; i < json.length; i++){                                        
                if((json.length -1)== i){
                    $(select_box).append('<option ' + setselect  + ' value="' + json[i].value  + '">' + json[i].option  + '</option>'); 
                }else{
                    $(select_box).append('<option value="' + json[i].value  + '">' + json[i].option  + '</option>');              
                }
            }                
            $(select_box).trigger("chosen:updated");               
            $(select_box).data('chosen').activate_action();                 
            bulid_select_trigger(select_box);               
        }            
    }); 
}
```

When using this the new value does not get inserted in the list, but when I am inspecting the values shows in the `<select>` tag its style is `display="none"`.

The actual list shows in a `<div>` with `class=ms-drop` with `<li>` tags.

I think the list is not updated when am using

```
  $(select_box).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

What am to do to update the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this library](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-refresh) the way to refresh the list is

```
$select.append($opt).multipleSelect("refresh");
```

Comment: but it doesnt set selected the last inserted value,may be it is because of am selecting from mysql db in asc order of name.what to do to set select the last inserted value

Comment: First get the id of last inserted value and then select that value from database and returned your value back to ajax

Comment: is there any search option in this?

Comment: you can search its library or use jquery for searching